# Angular - error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

Tags: angular

I am using Angular-11.

I have this code:

header.component.html:

> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-flat float-right" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)='logout()'>Sign out

header.component.ts:

```js
logout($event: MouseEvent){
  // tslint:disable-next-line:no-unused-expression
  $event.preventDefault();
  this.loggedIn = false;
  this.token.remove();
  this.auth.changeAuthStatus(false);
  this.router.navigateByUrl('/login');
  this.notify.info("Logout Succesfully", {timeout:2000});
}
```

I got this error:

> error TS2554: Expected 1 arguments, but got 0

> <a class="btn btn-danger btn-flat float-right" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)='logout()'>Sign out

It highlights logout().

How do I resolve this?

Thanks

Comment: your function expects a parameter : `logout($event: MouseEvent)`. You don't pass any parameter when using it into the template html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `logout` method is expecting a parameter (event) that you are not providing.

In the template you have to write `(click)='logout($event)'`.

`$event` is a variable provided by Angular representing the event.

Answer (score 1):

You should pass `$event` object.

```
(click)='logout($event)'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `logout` function has `MouseEvent` parameter and you don't send it in your html file.

Your html template should be

```
<a class="btn btn-danger btn-flat float-right" href="javascript:void(0)" (click)='logout($event)'>Sign out
```